# how to get value from online helm repo

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want to know some default value of helm chart.

For example, I want to know .Values.master.tag of stable/jenkins.
Is there a way to get this?

For now,
I think that I do `helm pull stable/jenkins` and then unzip tar and find out from values.yaml file.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think there is a dedicated `helm` command for that. What I usually do is checking the source, like for Jenkins: https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/jenkins/values.yaml. I know it's not perfect.

Comment: It this your clone https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7457 ?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```bash
helm show values stable/jenkins | yq '.master.tag'
```

P.S.: to not use outdated version:

```bash
helm repo update
helm show values jenkins/jenkins | yq '.master.tag'
```

Answer (score 2):

I can only think of a workaround by doing a `dry-run` install and then `grep`ing for the value.

E.g.

```
helm install --dry-run jenkins_temp stable/jenkins | grep value_name
```

From the [docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/getting_started/#adding-a-simple-template-call)

> When you want to test the template rendering, but not actually install anything, you can use `helm install --debug --dry-run ./mychart`. This will render the templates. But instead of installing the chart, it will return the rendered template to you so you can see the output

or you could `fetch` the Chart as a tar file.

```
helm fetch stable/jenkins --untar

less ./jenkins/values.yaml
```

Comment: less `./jenkins/values.yaml` surely?